# laravel seeding db through routes

Tags: laravel-5

I want to run a seeder command through web.php 
here is my code

> > Route::get('permission-seeder/{class}',function($class){
> >         Artisan::call("db:seed --class=$class"); });

I am getting this error

> ```
> Symfony \ Component \ Console \ Exception \ CommandNotFoundException
> The command "db:seed --class=PermissionSeeder" does not exist.
> ```

Although this seeder exists in the directory

can anyone sort it out

Comment: _I want to run a seeder command through web.php._ Why?

Comment: @martin Because i am working on a live project, first i work on local and then push my code. so instead of running command on server time and again. i make a route and running command with that.

Comment: But you _should_ be seeding your database via the command line.

Answer (score 1):

the way of passing parameter was wrong,
this is the right method to run seeders through routes

> Route::get('run-seeder/{class}',function($class){
>       Artisan::call("db:seed",array('--class'=>$class)); });